# Property 'authenticationService' is private and only accessible within class 'AdminComponent'

Tags: html, angular, firebase, deployment, angular-material

I am trying to deploy am angular project but I keep on getting this error from this class.

```
<div class="page-content">
    <app-breadcrumb [breadcrumbs]="breadcrumbs"></app-breadcrumb>
    <mat-toolbar class="toolbar-header">
        <mat-toolbar-row>
            <span class="font-larger">Welcome {{authenticationService.getName()}}!</span>
            <span class="mat-toolbar-spacer"></span>
        </mat-toolbar-row>
    </mat-toolbar>
    <mat-grid-list cols="3" rowHeight="240px" class="app-admin-tiles">
        <mat-grid-tile *ngFor="let element of tools"
                       [colspan]="element.cols"
                       [rowspan]="element.rows"
        >
            <app-admin-tile
                [color]="element.color"
                [text]="element.text"
                [icon]="element.icon"
                [url]="element.url"
                style="width: 100%;"
            ></app-admin-tile>
        </mat-grid-tile>
    </mat-grid-list>
</div>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C4bao.jpg)

Comment: it looks like you have private service in .ts file. Can you share your .ts file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expanding from my comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63560229/property-authenticationservice-is-private-and-only-accessible-within-class-ad/63560313?noredirect=1#comment112394263_63560313), it's isn't a good idea to bind a function in template expression or data-binding with default change detection strategy. Instead call the function in the component controller and bind the result from it in the template.

Try the following

Controller

```js
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  name: string;

  constructor(private authenticationService: AuthenticationService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.name = this.authenticationService.getName();    // <-- get name here
  }
}
```

Template

```html
<!-- Show only if the `name` is initialized with a valid value -->
<span *ngIf="name" class="font-larger">Welcome {{ name }}!</span>
...
```

Answer (score 1):

please assign `authenticationService.getName()` to a variable and use it in template..

in ts eg:

```
ngOnInit() {
this.name = authenticationService.getName();
}
```

in template use like `<span class="font-larger">Welcome {{name }}!</span>`

Comment: Not a good idea in default CD strategy. The function will be triggered for each CD cycle.

Comment: @MichaelD Thanks for seeing me, would you mind telling me how that happens..? from my understanding the value will be set on  onInit(), and it will be called only on the beginning of the component generation

Comment: You're right. The `this.name` variable is set only once at the initialisation of the component. But the binding `{{ name }}` is an expression. And this expression will be evaluated for each CD cycle. If it's a variable then it isn't an issue. It makes sure the template is rendering the current value held by the variable. In case of a function, similar to the variable, it'll be resolved in each CD. So each CD cycle will trigger the function. It's fine if the function is small and non-complex. But if the function is complex, then it might affect the performance.

Comment: @MichaelD what do u suggest i do?